# Alert stock email not received

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.2.4, out-of-stock, alert

I've configured my **Magento ver. 2.2.4** to send email to customers that have registered themselves for an stock alert when the product which is "out of stock" goes to be back in stock, but when I try to do this I don't receive any message for this, it's strange because I receive message for new users, newsletter, orders ... but not for a restock of an item. I've added the cron to "*****" in the database and the default cron is running on my server.

I've seen a lot of plugins with insane prices, but it's a Magento core feature so I don't want to pay a huge amount for this.

If anyone has a solution it would be nice if you share :D

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you changed any configuration for this?

Comment: what do you mean by this ? I've followed the last post : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Product-Stock-Alerts-Not-Sending/td-p/43032

Comment: @Coquelicot Have you found the solution?

Comment: "I've added the cron to "*****" in the database and the default cron is running on my server" - I am also facing the same issue, but I am not clear what you mentioned in the highlighted part.... Just backend cron timing is enough or do i need to configure something else for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. In my case the issue was related to the email communication settings. Please make sure your email communication is enabled.

Settings:

**Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings -> Disable Email Communications** should be "No".